# Problem with adding field in visual's title in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, ssas, powerbi-desktop, ssas-tabular, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm not able to customize the title of a visual with adding a field from a table with SSAS Cube Tabular like data source.

[Image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npoLY.png)

Could you help to resolve this issue ?

Thanks

I deleted and deployed the Cube many times but it didn't resolve the problem.

It doesn't accept any field for any tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation:

> Conditional formatting needs an aggregation or measure to be applied to the value. That's why you see 'First' or 'Last' in the Color by value example. **If you're building your report against an Analysis Service multidimensional cube, you won't be able to use an attribute for conditional formatting unless the cube owner has built a measure that provides the value.**

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-conditional-table-formatting#considerations-and-limitations

**Update**
Alternatively, see if the "Discourage Implicit Measures" option is set to to TRUE, in your SSAS cube - it needs to be FALSE.

Comment: it is a Tabular Cube. I did the same thing with others Cubes and it works but not with one of them and I don't understand why ...

Comment: Updated answer above with an update - see if that could be it.

Comment: I confirm that the option is true: 
"discourageImplicitMeasures": true,

Comment: Set it to false and it should work - updated answer to make that clear (sorry)

Comment: It works !! Thank you for your help !!